# Skip a row in a for each rowset loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops, datarow

I am looping through a dataset for each data row

```
 foreach (DataRow DRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

I would like to jump the current row when ever a if statement is true.
Any clue how to do it?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `continue`:

```
 foreach (DataRow DRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
     if(expression) 
         continue;
 }
```

`continue` skips the remaining part of the foreach block for the current element an continues at the next new element in your collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if(true) // escape condition met
         continue;
}
```

Comment: Poor choice to use "true" since that would skip ALL of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `continue` keyword...

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
    if(condition)
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `continue;` instruction tells a loop to skip the rest of the code and move to the next iteration.

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (--condition here--) continue;
}
```